# Intersection of all possible spanning trees of a connected, simple graph.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Is the intersection of all possible spanning trees of a simple, connected graph $G$ equal to the graph $(V_{G}, \varnothing)$?

I'm not sure if this is a trivial question or not. Although I'm going to tinker with it, I figured I'd post it just in case!

Edit: I think what I meant to include in here is that each vertex in $G$ has degree $>1$.

Comment: What if $G$ just consists of two vertices and one edge joining them?  Or have I missed the point?

Answer (score 2):

No. Take any connected graph with a vertex of degree one. All possible spanning trees must contain the edge containing that vertex.

Comment: Ah that's right. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: What if the graph $G$ has the property that for any vertex $v \in V_{G}$, $deg(v) > 1$?

Comment: It's still not true; consider any connected graph containing a cut-edge (i.e. an edge whose removal would result in the graph becoming disconnected).

Comment: Yes, okay. Thank you again.